# Strange logs when vaadin page opened in osgi

Tags: osgi, vaadin

I have following logs when opening a vaadin page.
The strange logs stop when I close my webpage.

```
[qtp948395645-39] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 447/447
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST / on AsyncHttpConnection@5444c658,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=48,c=0},r=11
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Got Session ID 1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s from cookie
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@19868320
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s@1806836909
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet ||/ -> org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-158d255c
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
[qtp948395645-39 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /  200 handled=true
[qtp948395645-39] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@11dfd090{l(/10.221.137.111:56461)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@5444c658,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=48,c=0},r=11}
[qtp948395645-39] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
[qtp948395645-36] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 474/474
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js on AsyncHttpConnection@5444c658,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=48,c=0},r=12
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Got Session ID 1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s from cookie
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@19868320
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s@1806836909
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet ||/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js -> org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-158d255c
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
[qtp948395645-36 - /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1443457921853] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js  200 handled=true
[qtp948395645-36] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@11dfd090{l(/10.221.137.111:56461)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@5444c658,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=48,c=0},r=12}
[qtp948395645-40] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 731/731
[qtp948395645-36] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST / on AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=48,c=246},r=3
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Got Session ID 1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s from cookie
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@19868320
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s@1806836909
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet ||/ -> org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-158d255c
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] INFO com.bekaert.handling.ui.core - Rebuilding session from cookie for user 'admin'
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] WARN com.bekaert.handling.ui.core.main.ErrorView - Entered in error view: 
[qtp948395645-40 - /?v-1443457921854] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /  200 handled=true
[qtp948395645-40] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@61bf045{l(/10.221.137.111:56462)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=48,c=246},r=3}
[qtp948395645-40] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 695/695
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST /UIDL/ on AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=48,c=200},r=4
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/UIDL/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/UIDL/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Got Session ID 1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s from cookie
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@19868320
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s@1806836909
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet ||/UIDL/ -> org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-158d255c
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
[qtp948395645-42 - /UIDL/?v-wsver=7.5.5&v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /UIDL/  200 handled=true
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@61bf045{l(/10.221.137.111:56462)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=48,c=200},r=4}
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 607/607
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST /UIDL/ on AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=48,c=126},r=5
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/UIDL/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/UIDL/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Got Session ID 1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s from cookie
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@19868320
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s@1806836909
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet ||/UIDL/ -> org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-158d255c
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
[qtp948395645-37 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /UIDL/  200 handled=true
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@61bf045{l(/10.221.137.111:56462)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=48,c=126},r=5}
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] DEBUG com.bekaert.handling.order.location.sap.connector.impl - Start search for new SAP orders
[qtp948395645-39] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 607/607
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST /UIDL/ on AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=48,c=126},r=6
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/UIDL/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/UIDL/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Got Session ID 1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s from cookie
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@19868320
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:1mddljaq8cpy11l0btqfs6p34s@1806836909
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet ||/UIDL/ -> org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-158d255c
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
[qtp948395645-39 - /UIDL/?v-uiId=1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /UIDL/  200 handled=true
[qtp948395645-39] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@61bf045{l(/10.221.137.111:56462)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=48,c=126},r=6}
[qtp948395645-39] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
[qtp948395645-36] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - ishut SCEP@61bf045{l(/10.221.137.111:56462)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=-3},r=6}
[qtp948395645-36] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled -1/0
[qtp948395645-36] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Disabled read interest while writing response SCEP@61bf045{l(/10.221.137.111:56462)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=-3},r=6}
[qtp948395645-36] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@61bf045{l(/10.221.137.111:56462)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=-3},r=6}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - destroyEndPoint SCEP@61bf045{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:80),s=0,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=-3},r=6}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection - closed AsyncHttpConnection@34d39e39,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=-3},r=6
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - ishut SCEP@5534412c{l(/10.221.137.111:56463)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@cf40a17,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled -1/0
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Disabled read interest while writing response SCEP@5534412c{l(/10.221.137.111:56463)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@cf40a17,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@5534412c{l(/10.221.137.111:56463)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@cf40a17,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - ishut SCEP@1dcb12a9{l(/10.221.137.111:56464)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@6a011d1d,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled -1/0
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - destroyEndPoint SCEP@5534412c{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:80),s=0,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@cf40a17,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Disabled read interest while writing response SCEP@1dcb12a9{l(/10.221.137.111:56464)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@6a011d1d,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection - closed AsyncHttpConnection@cf40a17,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@1dcb12a9{l(/10.221.137.111:56464)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@6a011d1d,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - ishut SCEP@6d491226{l(/10.221.137.111:56466)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2c01d086,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled -1/0
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Disabled read interest while writing response SCEP@6d491226{l(/10.221.137.111:56466)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2c01d086,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-42] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@6d491226{l(/10.221.137.111:56466)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2c01d086,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - destroyEndPoint SCEP@1dcb12a9{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:80),s=0,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@6a011d1d,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection - closed AsyncHttpConnection@6a011d1d,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - destroyEndPoint SCEP@6d491226{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:80),s=0,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2c01d086,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection - closed AsyncHttpConnection@2c01d086,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - ishut SCEP@387f2edf{l(/10.221.137.111:56465)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@574b3210,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled -1/0
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Disabled read interest while writing response SCEP@387f2edf{l(/10.221.137.111:56465)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@574b3210,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@387f2edf{l(/10.221.137.111:56465)<->r(/10.224.129.14:80),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@574b3210,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - destroyEndPoint SCEP@387f2edf{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:80),s=0,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@574b3210,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
[qtp948395645-35 Selector0] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection - closed AsyncHttpConnection@574b3210,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0
[Timer-2] INFO org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComOxidRuntime - Running ClientPingTimerTask !
[Timer-2] INFO org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComOxidRuntime - Within ClientPingTimerTask: holder.currentSetOIDs, current size of which is 2
[Timer-2] INFO org.jinterop.dcom.core.PingObject - Simple Ping going for setId: 00000: 00 00 00 05 65 74 29 12                          |....et).        |
[Timer-2] INFO org.jinterop - 
 Sending REQUEST
[Timer-2] INFO org.jinterop - 
 Recieved RESPONSE
[Timer-2] INFO org.jinterop.dcom.core.PingObject - Simple Ping Succeeded
[Timer-2] INFO org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComOxidRuntime - Within ClientPingTimerTask: holder.seqNum 1
```

I don't know what all this means.
Also, it doesn't happen always. If I restart my osgi program, there is a 1/2 change I have this problem.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you don't understand from this log. Also what do you want to find out?

Comment: I was wrong, sorry. I thought this was causing some problems, but I realize these are logs with loglevel DEBUG.
Reason I suddenly saw this was because the configuration of my logging had changed.